# How I can to optimize my "The maximum sum value of ranges"

Tags: python, optimization

I need to optimize my code
Given a list of integers A, for each pair of integers (first, last) in list ranges, calculate the sum of the values in A between indices first and last (both inclusive), and return the greatest resulting sum.

Example
A = [1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1]
ranges = [(1, 3), (0, 4), (6, 8)]

result = 6

Notes:
The list of ranges will never be empty
each integers-list : 100000 elements
each ranges-list : 10000 elements

```
def max_sum(a, ranges):
    list_sum = []
    
    for r in ranges:
        
        indexes = []
        for i in range(r[0], r[-1] + 1):
            indexes.append(i)
        
        suma = 0
        for i in indexes:
            suma += a[i]

        list_sum.append(suma)
        
    return max(list_sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

simply

```
max([sum(a[r[0]:r[1]]) for r in ranges])
```

You are iterating over the ranges, summing the array in the range value and maximizing it.

You can theoretically optimize it by summing the array at all points and keeping the score, then iterating over the ranges and sutracting the sum at the beginning from the sum at the end (you won't have to go over the array elements multiple times)

Answer (score 1):

Compute and subtract prefix sums:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def max_sum(a, ranges):
    p = 0, *accumulate(a)
    return max(p[j+1] - p[i] for i, j in ranges)
```

Answer (score -1):

In python, a good rule of thumb for optimization is to replace explicit loops with built-in functions. In this case, you may replace your function with the simpler:

```
def max_sum(a, ranges):
    list_sum = []

    for r in ranges:
        list_sum.append(sum(a[r[0]:r[-1]+1]))
    
return max(list_sum)
```

Inside the for loop, you may use the built-in sum function for lists, selecting the indices that you want summed with the slicing notation `a[index0:index1]`. It is therefore also not necessary to create a separate list holding the values of the indices.

You can make the function even more compact by using the list-comprehension syntax:

`max([sum(a[r[0]:r[-1]+1]) for r in ranges])`

This way, a list of sums is created, and the max is evaluated afterwards. This syntax sometimes makes it more clear what it is exactly that you want to compute (here, the maximum of a list of sums), without creating additional variables (here, `list_sum`).

Running the code on my computer a million times with your function takes about 2.7 seconds, and with my suggestion only 1.6 seconds. Note that the larger the sums, the more will `sum()` outperform the explicit loop.